# Characterizing the inter-arrival time of software threads

Tags: time-series, clustering, variance, predictive-models, forecasting

For a multi-threaded application, I want to identify the nature of the application based on the arrival times of each thread. Example(Are thread launch spaced regularly, are they bursty in nature or are they highly dynamic). To identify this, the starting time of each thread is measured. The variance is calculated for time taken between every thread launch. This gives an idea of the spread in inter-arrival times. More spread indicates high dynamism. Based on the percentage of zscores that fall within the first level of standard deviation, a prediction is made on the level of dynamism (if more than 50% of values falls within one standard deviation - low dynamism otherwise high dynamism). Is this approach correct? Also, the values obtained for the starting time of each thread is only for a sample and not for the whole population. For this reason, the standard deviation is calculated using n-1. Are there any exisiting techniques for better estimation? Would clustering the values based on similarity help in any way? I'd highly appreciate it if you could point me to any reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you basically want to estimate the distribution of the inter-arrival time between threads?

Comment: Yes, to estimate the distribution based on inter-arrival time and use the estimate to characterize the properties of the application.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do with the estimate; predict the interarrival time of the next process, or somesuch forecasting?

Comment: Yes, that would do. Also any reference to statistical techniques applicable to this problem domain would be of great help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If your prediction is specifically "low-dynamism" vs. "high-dynamism" you could run a [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) on your observations. This would give you effectively a percentage probability of one of the two outcomes you need to forecast. Logistic regression (or any kind of regression for that matter) includes an analysis of the IVs distribution and significance, similar to the z-score analysis you describe in your question.

But the analysis you're doing now sounds reasonable if you simply want to look at the dispersion of the threads start. The unbiased sd estimator n-1 is only required if you have a small number of observations, say < 50.